# Connecting two different 'user' tables into one single table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to connect three tables so when the admin inserts one row in a table, that row will be copied and pasted in another table? Or how to define a relationship between them?

I have three tables in a database, they are `tb_student`, `tb_teacher`, `tb_user`. Their DDL design is shown below:

```
-- Teacher Table: Primary Key is `id_teacher`

CREATE TABLE `tb_teacher` (
  `id_teacher` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','nonactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Sample Data

INSERT INTO `tb_teacher` (`id_teacher`, `name`, `status`) VALUES
('14320', 'Lenny Belardo', 'active'),
('14323', 'Shoffin Nahwa Utama', 'nonactive');

-- Student Table: Primary Key is `id_student`

CREATE TABLE `tb_student` (
  `id_student` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `entry_year` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','nonactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Sample Data

INSERT INTO `tb_student` (`id_student`, `name`, `entry_year`, `status`) VALUES
('352014110577', 'Buddha Gautama', '2014', 'active'),
('352014121153', 'Harie Tanoesoedibjo', '2015', 'active');
```

`tb_user` is kind of like the combination of in both `tb_student` and `tb_teacher`

```
-- tb_user: Primary key is ID    

CREATE TABLE `tb_user` (
  `id_user` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `entry_year` varchar(4) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `level` enum('admin','teacher','student') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','nonactive') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I intend to create accounts for both students and teachers; therefore, a `user` table is necessary to create. The data type from `tb_student.id_student` and `tb_teacher.id_teacher` is matching with `tb_user.id_user` which is `VARCHAR(13)`. The sample data is as the following:

```
INSERT INTO `tb_user` (`id_user`, `username`, `name`, `password`, `entry_year`, `level`, `status`) VALUES
('14231', 'spectrum@unida.gontor.ac.id', 'Nunik Siti Nurzanah', '123456', '2014', 'teacher', 'active'),
('352014121188', 'tukiyem@ngebel.udik.gov.id', 'Tukiyem', '123456', '2012', 'student', 'active');
```

Where the id `14231` is a teacher and the id `352014121188` is a student.

How to define a relationship between these three tables so that when the admin inserts a new row of student/teacher, the data is copied automatically to the user table?

Right now I still need to insert the data for these three tables manually or one-by-one.

Comment: don't copy, read up on normalization. `tb_student` and `tb_teacher` need the `tb_user` primary key only. The rest can be derived with `JOIN`s

Comment: *when the admin insert one row in a table, that row will be copied and pasted in another table.* Trigger can do it, of course. But I agree with **danblack** that normalization is the best solution.

Comment: Could you kindly provide any reference or tutorial that explain normalization application in any case like this? @danblack. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: Single table**

If you don't really have a lot of unique columns that belong only in `tb_student` or in `tb_teacher`, then it might make sense to combine everything in the `tb_user` table, and there would be no need for the `tb_teacher` and `tb_student` tables. They would be superfluous. But there could be reasons for keeping them separate, like maybe relationships to the other tables in your schema.

**Option 2: Normalisation**

So if you try to follow the principles of normalisation, and keep three separate tables, then all columns that are unique to the `tb_student` tables should be found only there, and likewise with the `tb_teacher` table. (You don't have anything unique to the `tb_teacher` table at the moment, but maybe you'll think of something later?) You will need to add a column e.g. `id_tb_user` in each of the `tb_student` and `tb_teacher` tables, and declare [foreign key constraints](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/foreign-keys/) for these columns referring to the `tb_user` table. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_teacher (
...
  id_tb_user int unsigned,
...
  CONSTRAINT tb_teacher_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (id_tb_user)
    REFERENCES tb_user(id_user)
...
)
```

The `tb_user` table will contain all the shared columns: `name`, `status` and some of the other columns you already have, but not `entry_year`.

To retrieve information about students, including info about them in the `tb_user` table, you will then use a query with a simple `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.id_student, 
  s.entry_year, 
  u.username, 
  u.name -- + any other columns you want
FROM tb_student s
  INNER JOIN tb_user u ON s.id_tb_user = u.id_user
WHERE 
  u.username = 'spectrum@unida.gontor.ac.id'; 
  -- or any other condition you want
```

(To retrieve info about students and teachers in a single query, use instead two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.)

By the way, you should also explicitly declare your primary keys as such. It's also a good idea to use `int unsigned` as the data type for these columns (or even `bigint unsigned`, although that is rarely needed), and it's also often a good idea to use [`auto_increment`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment/) (see also the [FAQ](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/auto_increment-faq/)) so that MariaDB/MySQL does the job of generating a new id when you insert a new row:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_user (
    `id_user` int unsigned auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
```